# how do i call jQuery in rails after the page has loaded in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

i have a search page on a rails app, the search results are appended with Ajax  at this point, jQuery has already fired, so the new view jQuery functions cannot work, how can do i go around it, or do i have to use inline javaScript, and if so, where do i put my javaScript script

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()"> add </button>
```

heres my jQuery

```
   $("span.block-user").click(function(){    
    var num = $(this).context.id;
    var dis = $(this).css("display"); 
    if (($("div#block_"+ num).css("display")) == "block") {
        $("div#block_"+ num).css("display", "none"); 
    } else if( num == "none"){
        $("div#block_"+ num).css("display", "block"); 
        // myTimeOut
    } else {
        $("div#block_"+ num).css("display", "block"); 
    }

   })
```

This is my view and partial

```
   <div class="post_<%= post.id%>"  > 
<span style="float:left;"> <%= post.body %></span>
      <span style="float: right;"class="block-user" id="<%= post.id %>" >
        <div class="block-user-div" id="block_<%= post.id %>">
          <%= render @partial %> 
        </div> 
         |  
      </span>
</div>
```

index.js

```
$('#my-posts').append('<%= j render @posts %>');
```

This is a simple post index view, on the left is a post on the right is a block modal, it works at all times when i load the page. i click on the "span.block-user" the modal box displays.
heres  my issue, if i render another post, via Ajax calls without reloading the page, nothing happens when i click the "span.block-user", not on the console on activity is recorded on the window.
I added the onclick on the span.block-user itself, that works fine, i don't think its safe though so what could it be?

Comment: Please post a working example after reading: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: _at this point_ - at _what_ point? At the point you have a search page on a rails app? Then this: _jQuery has already fired, so the new view jQuery functions cannot work_ -  jQuery is invoked by JavaScript in the browser and sits resident in the global scope until it is called. So what do you mean _jQuery functions cannot work_? How you do you _go around it_ - what is "_it_" precisely? Your question is very ambiguous - please try to clarify your meaning.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that when you replace your view partial in the page the `click` event handler is no longer bound to anything since the element it _was_ bound to is no longer in the DOM. You have two choices: 1) You will need to reattach the `click` event handler each time you load a new post OR 2) use event delegation and move the `click` event handler to a "container" element that does not get replaced with each new post.

Comment: You have to delgate the event to the wrapper, check the doc https://api.jquery.com/on/ the secion **Direct and delegated event handlers**

Comment: Thanks just what i needed